# Functional difference between ROS2 spin_some, spin_once, and spin_until_future

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that spin_once will just query once, but I'm not sure when spin_some would be a better choice or under what situations it would return. Spin until... is for service callbacks I've seen but any other time that would be helpful?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296480/functional-difference-between-ros2-spin_some,-spin_once,-and-spin_until_future/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`spin_once` will process one item in the executor, it may or may not be the thing you expect, however. Sometimes you just want to spin one thing at a time periodically, and don't care what it is.

Other times you want to spin one thing at a time until something has completed, this is where `spin_until_future_complete` is useful, as it basically does `while(future.not_done()) executor.spin_once()`. It's a bit more complicated than that, but essentially that's what it is doing. You could do this yourself, so `spin_until_future_complete` is just a convenience function.

`spin_some` is slightly different. Basically it spins, executing zero to many items, until it is "idle", basically until there's a time where there is nothing for the executor to do. Some people might assume that `spin_some` would only process what available when it is called, exiting even if there's more work to be done after a period of time. There's an issue and pull request to try and make it behave that way, but they're still in progress:

- https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/471
- https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/472

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45380/rhogan/) on 2019-09-04**:
I am having trouble finding literature on using ROS2 executors and getting a pub/sub file working. Do you know anywhere I can look to get more information or a hands on tutorial?

**Comment by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on 2020-04-09**:
@rhogan check these out.

- Python https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#pypubsub
- C++ https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#cpppubsub